# Difference between LIMIT N and FETCH NEXT N ROWS?

Tags: offset-fetch

The two queries below seem equivalent. Is one better than the other? e.g. in terms of performance.

```
select * from some_table offset 10 limit 10;
```

```
select * from some_table offset 10 fetch next 10 rows;
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: The biggest difference: the second one is standard SQL, the first one is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is one better than the other? e.g. in terms of performance.

No, they just differ in syntax.

**Both achieve pagination, with the same exact performance.**

The first statement uses the `LIMIT` clause, which is not part of standard SQL and originates as a vendor SQL extension. The second statement uses the `FETCH` clause, which was first introduced in the official SQL:2008 standard.

With links to official documentation, here's a table showing support for each statement in various major database engines:

| Database Engine | First statement (`LIMIT`) | Second statement (`FETCH NEXT`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MySQL 8.0.33 | [Supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) ✅ | [Not supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) ❌ |
| PostgreSQL 15.3 | [Supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html) ✅ | [Supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html) ✅ |
| Microsoft SQL Server 2022 | [Not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ❌ | [Supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ✅ |
| Oracle 19c | [Not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html) ❌ | [Not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html) ❌ |
| SQLite 3.42.0 | [Supported](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) ✅ | [Not supported](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) ❌ |

---

You can validate the performance aspect yourself using a sample PostgreSQL database and comparing the execution plans:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  column1 TEXT,
  column2 INTEGER,
  column3 FLOAT,
  column4 DATE
);

INSERT INTO some_table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT 
  md5(random()::text)::TEXT,
  floor(random() * 100)::INTEGER,
  random()::FLOAT,
  CURRENT_DATE - (random() * 365)::INTEGER
FROM generate_series(1, 100);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM some_table OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM some_table OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

The output will show the exact same execution plan for both:

```sql
postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM some_table OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10;
                                                  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.30..0.60 rows=10 width=53) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on some_table  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=53) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=20 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 2.478 ms
 Execution Time: 0.044 ms
(4 rows)


postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM some_table OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
                                                  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.30..0.60 rows=10 width=53) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on some_table  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=53) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=20 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.051 ms
 Execution Time: 0.020 ms
(4 rows)
```

The first one is visualised [here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/b0498e08e250c6de) and the second one is visualised [here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/79def872114c12g3).